# Cake PHP Upload plugin - How to store the thumbnail path in the database

Tags: image, cakephp, plugins, model, upload

I have installed Upload plugin for cakephp.
I've been trying to figure out how to store the thumbnail path or thumbnail name inside a field called image_thumb in my table called Portfolio. I want to store this the same way I can store the original image name. The dir option for the image is there but there is no such thing for thumbnail dir.

My model code where I used upload plugin is this:

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Upload.Upload' => array(
        'image' => array(

            'fields' => array(
                'dir' => 'image'
            ),

            'thumbnailSizes' => array(
                'small' => '640x480',
            ),

            'thumbnailName' => '{filename}_{size}_{geometry}',

            'thumbnailPath' => '{ROOT}webroot{DS}img{DS}{model}{DS}Thumbnails{DS}'
        )
    )
);
```

Controller, the add function, where the plugin happens I assume (I haven't changed anything here though,
 it is the baked code)

```
public function admin_add() {
        $this->layout='admin';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Portfolio->create();
            if ($this->Portfolio->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The portfolio has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The portfolio could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
```

When the image path is uploaded in database, the image itself and thumbnails are saved in the specified directories in my application. But I want to save the path of the thumbnails inside the database soe that I can use it in my view.

Would really appreciate the help as I'm so new to cakephp and I have to figure it out in a short amount of time.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is controller code that you have sent this directory to database?

Comment: use  'dir'=>'image_thumb' because it's your field name.

Comment: I have updated the code with the controller.
but dir is for the original image. what about the thumbnail?.
I have a image field where I save the image name there. but the image_thumb I want to save the thumb name there

Comment: your database field name is image_thumb ? If yes you have given a wrong directory to save path.

Answer (score 0):

You may make mistake in here it should be

```
'fields' => array(
                'dir' => 'image_thumb'         //table field name
            ),
```

Comment: I have both image and image_thumb as two separate fields in my database. when I use dir=>image it saves the name of my image inside the image field in the database. In addition, it creates a thumbnail, name it, and put it inside the specified folder. But I wan to save the thumbnail name inside my image_thumb field so I can use it inside view!